# Why is core resistance modeled to be parallel to the primary winding of ideal part of a real transformer?

Tags: transformer

When a real transformer is modeled to a simpler circuit, it is shown that the core resistance or a resistance model which basically describes eddy current and hysteresis loss is in parallel with the ideal primary winding part. Why is that resistance considered in parallel instead of series? I know that the hysteresis loss and eddy current depends on the flux of the primary winding but what does it have to do with the parallel orientation?

Comment: MSKB if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification. Also note that your latest question has been closed to it being almost a carbon copy of this one. However, if you can explain why in comments that it should stand on its own then I'll vote to reopen it. If necessary I will amend my answer here for any issues arising in your newer question that were not covered here. I'll add one now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Why is that resistance considered in parallel instead of series? I
> know that the hysteresis loss and eddy current depends on the flux of
> the primary winding but what does it have to do with the parallel
> orientation?*

Both eddy currents and core flux are proportional to the applied voltage and, are \$\text{not-at-all}^1\$ dependent on the secondary load currents or the primary referred secondary load currents hence, there is **absolutely no alternative** other than to model them as parallel components (so that they get worse with a bigger primary voltage and, are largely unaffected by primary or secondary load currents).

---

\$\text{not-at-all}^1\$ is a little to convenient to say when it comes to core flux and associated components. In fact, as the load current increases, the voltage appearing on the components \$R_C\$ and \$L_M\$ slightly reduces and, this slightly alleviates the problems associated with core saturation and eddy currents. Equivalent circuit from [my basic website](http://www.stades.co.uk/#transformers): -

[image]